# Permission Denied when trying to import an sql file on my linux system

Tags: postgresql, linux

I'm trying to import a table to a database called 'test' that I've already created as the postgres superuser. The file i.e. the table is in a drive/filesystem that's already mounted.

*I'm logged into the postgres user. And other users have read, write and execute permissions for this file.

When I use the following command

```
\i '/run/media/qazizarifulislam/Windows_files/Work/RA/learning-postgres/person.sql'
```

I get the error- /run/media/qazizarifulislam/Windows_files/Work/RA/learning-postgres/person.sql: Permission denied

where,

- qazizarifulislam is my username
- Windows_files is the filesystem (It's an NFTS and not an external HDD or SDD)
- The remaining portions are just subfolders.
- person.sql is a file that contains lines that creates the table and then has querries that inserts records into the table. (Preview shown below)

[image]

How do I fix this/ import the table?

Comment: How did you validate that the file is readable? The OS obviously tells you it isn't. I'm inclined to trust it.

Comment: Doing an ls -la in the working directory gives me -rwxrwxrwx.
Although this was from the qazizarifulislam user.

Comment: I tried cd'ing into the folder where this file is kept from the postgres user and permission was denied here as well. How do I give postgres access to my files?

Comment: I guess that depends on who "you" are, relative to `postgres`. May be `chmod`? In any case, this seems to be off-topic here.

Comment: You need to distinguish between the OS user named 'postgres', and the PostgreSQL user named 'postgres'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was deeper and not really related to user roles. My hard drives weren't being mounted into the mnt directory. They were being mounted into a temporary directory. I changed settings using disks so that they're automatically mounted into mnt. Everything worked after that.

Comment: I apologize for not including the steps. It's hard to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system user needs read access to the file *and read as well as execute permissions on all directories in the path*. You are probably lacking the latter.

Note that the operating system user I am talking about is *not* the PostgreSQL user (typically `postgres`), but the operating system user that started `psql`.

If you cannot find a permission problem, try to disable SE-Linux.

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL you should create a 'role' to access the DB, then use psql with the -U option as your regular linux user.

To create a role; As your postgres user run `createuser --interactive`

Then see the docs on altering your database 'test' to be owned by that new 'role':
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-alterdatabase.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/database-roles.html